# three.js: jumpy animation (– due to float imprecision?)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using three.js on a separate canvas on top of a openlayers map. the way I synchronize the view of the map and the three.js camera (which looks straight down onto the map) works fine, and looks like this:

```
function updateThreeCam(
    group, // three.js group — has camera in it
    view, // ol3 view
    map // ol3 map
) {
    // get visible part of map
    const extent = getViewExtent(view, map);
    const h = ol.extent.getHeight(extent);
    const mapCenter = ol.extent.getCenter(extent);

    // calculates how for away from the ground the camera has to
    // be to match the currently visible part of the map
    const camDist = h / (2 * Math.tan(constants.CAM_V_FOV_RAD / 2));

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); // needed?

    group.position.set(...mapCenter, camDist);
    group.updateMatrixWorld();
}
```

however, when I am animating the flight of an object from in front of the camera down to the ground, the movement is not smooth: the vertical movement is jumping a lot. https://jsbin.com/qohutabofe/2/edit?js,output

[image]

this is the animation code:

```
// construct a spline to animate along
const waypoints = [
    objStartPosition,
    objEndPosition,
];
const pathSpline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(waypoints);
// const pathSpline = new THREE.LineCurve3(...waypoints);
startTime = Date.now();

// [...]

function animate() {
    const diff = Date.now() - startTime;
    const t = diff / aniDuration;

    // sample curve at `t`
    const pos = pathSpline.getPointAt(t);

    // update position
    obj.position.copy(pos);

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
```

what is weird is that I don't really see the jumps in the sampled positions:

[image]

---

as you can see the map coordinates tend to be very big numbers. that's why I thought it might be a float precision issue. — dividing everything by 1000 indeed seems to help. there is just two new problems with that:

- the foreshortening effect is way less drastic / not realistic anymore
- panning does not work as expected anymore: the rectangle on the ground does not stay in its position

https://jsbin.com/bujepediro/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Try the three.js dev branch. `<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/build/three.js"></script>`

Comment: @WestLangley yep, it works fine with the `dev` version. – was that just a hunch you had, or do you have any more insight that you can share?

Comment: See this [recent three.js issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/10702).